# js variable or user input to change DateFormat in bootstrap date picker using

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstarp datepicker :[DatepickerLink](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=2&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)

but I need to change the format on the basis of a variable ,how to do that?

I am trying to use this code

```
if (sessionStorage.Dateformat && sessionStorage.Dateformat != '') {
                    dateFormat = sessionStorage.Dateformat;

                }
else{
      dateFormat='dd-M-yyyy';
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
  $('#sand .input-group.date').datepicker({
                    format: dateFormat,
                    todayHighlight: true
                });
```

but it is saying invalid date format
///////For Information This way is working

```
 $('#sand .input-group.date').datepicker({
                        format: 'dd-M-yyyy',
                        todayHighlight: true
                    });
```

Comment: Check format of date-picker (eg: dd-mm-yyyy) and get your input in the same format to not get the error.

Comment: date format is correct but the it is not taking the way i wan like by setting format:dateFormat where datefomat is a variable

Comment: Perhaps its taking it as a String. Use Javascript to ensure conversion correct format console.log output and paste here. Also I am not sure dateFormat='dd-M-yyyy' actually exists. One thing is for sure the format you are passing is not the correct format, so mess around with that and things will work out.

Comment: But I am damn sure it is correct as i worked on that from last 1 week its a plugin where we use this format to set date like 12-Dec-2015

Answer (score 1):

the format of your date is incorrect:

```
{
  dateFormat='dd-mm-yyyy';
}
```

Comment: its a correct format i have checked that one by giving manually

Comment: the dateformat = dd-M-yyyy does not exist. can you post a detailed error log?

Comment: have you check the link there you can see the date format is working its a plugin where 12-Dec-2014 is given in dd-M-yyyy